# Mage_Weee Module

Tags: magento-1.7, module, performance

I have looked around but I cannot find exactly what is the purpose of the module:

> Mage_Weee

I would like to disable it but I want to be sure what I am doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module relates to the EU WEEE Directive (Waste Electrical and Electronic Equipment), but in Magento can actually be used for any products you need to apply a fixed tax amount to.

To cover your costs, it gives you the ability to setup FPT (fixed product tax) on products where you need to supply a service to the customer after purchase.  In the case of WEEE, you are required to offer the customer a means by which to recycle their electrical items through you which will obviously cost your business a certain amount.

I'm not sure of the ramifications of disabling the module in terms functionality and tax calculations - you'll have to test that yourself, but if you don't sell any products which need a fixed product tax then you at least don't require the functionality the module offers.

Comment: No worries.  Can you mark my answer as correct if you think it is?